# Java apache cli arguments order

Tags: java, command-line, arguments, apache-commons, apache-commons-cli

I'm using following code to display help screen for the user

```
HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
formatter.printHelp("asd123", buildOptions());
```

The arguments are printed in lexicographical order. Is there any way to print them in the order they were added?

Comment: Since v1.3 you can print in the same order you added the options. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HelpFormatter supports setting a different Comparator, see the [javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/HelpFormatter.html#setOptionComparator%28java.util.Comparator%29).

Therefore it should be possible to add a new [java.util.Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which knows about the intended order and set it for the HelpFormatter via

```
formatter.setOptionComparator(comparator)
```

Then `printHelp()` should use the order that you provide.

If you cannot do that then the only option I see is to file an enhancement request with commons-cli.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I don't want to change anything in the way options are added. Your solution requires writing additional code to store the order and I want to avoid it.

Comment: Then the answer as far as I see is "no with the current version of commons-cli, you will need to file an enhancement request with commons-cli to get this added as option to HelpFormatter."